# Sent HTTP request with Credential in blackberry

Tags: http, blackberry, networkcredentials

I am trying to call HTTP request with network credential in blackberry. i have already implement on Java, Android it's working fine but not working on blackberry. Following step i have done in blackberry.

For set Network credential i have added three following jar.

1. commons-codec-1.6.jar
2. commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
3. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

add this jar files are in blackberry project.

Following sample Code that work fine in Core Java.

```
 try{
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://www.google.com");
        get.setDoAuthentication( true );
        try {
            int status = client.executeMethod( get );
            System.out.println(status + "\n" + get.getResponseBodyAsString());

        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:>>>>>>"+e);
    }
```

Now there are not error on code but whenever try to click on application icon error face like "error starting appName: Module 'commons-httpclient-3.0.1' not found"

Can any one suggest what's this error say.

Comment: The error just means that the library required for `HttpClient` was not found. You might want to try `HttpConnection` instead?

Comment: i have add jar and there are not compilation error. Code compile proper.

Comment: No doubt it does...but it seems that it isn't supported by BB...

Comment: BlackBerry is based on JavaME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BB does not support `HttpClient`. But it does support J2ME's `HttpConnection` and is quite similar to `HttpClient`, so you can easily adjust with it. Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
try{
HttpConnection mConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(urlToPost);

mConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
mConn.setRequestProperty("IF-Modified-Since", "20 Jan 2001 16:19:14 GMT");
mConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-1.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
mConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-CA");
//---------------------------------------------------
mConn.setRequestProperty("User",usr);
mConn.setRequestProperty("pass",pass);

//---------------------------------------------------
catch(Exception e){//---handle your exceptions---//}
} finally {
    mConn.close();//don't forget to close connections, only a limited number are available
}
```

[This](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/network/) is a good article for beter understanding.